# Issue in logout Spring Boot Security?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, security, logout, boot

I have a problem with my project that contains the login page and the logout button, but when I log in for the first time, it is successful, but when I click the logout button, the process is successful, I am directed to the login page, but when I login again, I am directed to the page 404 not Found

```
@Configuration
public class Security {

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsManager userDetailsManager(DataSource dataSource) {


        return new JdbcUserDetailsManager(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.authorizeHttpRequests(coinfigurer -> coinfigurer.anyRequest().
                            authenticated()).
                  formLogin(form -> form.  loginPage("/LoginPage")
                            .login ProcessingUrl("/List-Employees")
                            .permit All()
                  )

                  .logout(logout -> logout.  permit   All());
        return http Security. build();
    }


}
```

```
this Login Code

<!DOCTYPE >
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Login Page</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <div id="loginbox" style="margin-top: 50px;" class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-2">
        <div class="card border-info">
            <div class="card-header bg-info">
                Sign In
            </div>

            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="card-text">

                    <!-- Login Form -->
                    <form action="#" th:action="@{List-Employees}" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">

                        <!-- Place for messages: error, alert etc ... -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-xs-15">
                                <div>
                                    <!-- Check for login error -->
                                    <div  th:if="${param.error}">
                                        <div class="alert alert-danger col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10">
                                            Invalid username and password.
                                        </di
```

```
this Log in Controller

enter image description here@Controller
public class LoginController {
    @GetMapping("/LoginPage")
    public String showMyLoginPage() {
        return "View/fancy-login";
    }

    

}
```

```
this Log in Controller

enter image description here@Controller
public class LoginController {
    @GetMapping("/LoginPage")
    public String showMyLoginPage() {
        return "View/fancy-login";
    }

    

}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Employee System</title>
</head>

<body style="background-image: url('/HR-Auromation.webp'); background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat;">

<div class="container">

    <h3 style="text-align:center;color:black">Employee Dashboard</h3>
    <hr>


    <a th:href="@{/Employees/Show}"

       class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mb-3">
        Add Employee
    </a>
    <hr>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/logout}" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Logout"/>
    </form>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead class="table-dark">
        <tr>
            <th> Employee First Name</th>
            <th> Employee Last Name</th>
            <th>Educational Specialization</th>
            <th>Higher Education of the employee</th>
            <th> Home Address</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Phone Number</th>
            <th>National Number</th>
            <th>Date of Birth</th>
            <th>date Of Employment</th>
            <th>Jop Title</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
        <tr th:each="tempEmployee : ${Employees}">
            <td style="color:black"><b th:text="${tempEmployee.firstName}"></b></td>
            <td style="color:black"><b th:text="${tempEmployee.lastName}"></b></td>
            <td style="color:black"><b th:text="${tempEmployee.educationalSpecialization}"></b></td>
            <td style="color:black"><b th:text="${tempEmployee.HigherEducation}"></b></td>
            <td style="color:black"><b th:text="${tempEmployee.homeAddress}"></b></td>
            <td style="color:black"><b th:text="${tempEmployee.email}"></b></td>
            <td style="color:black"><b th:text="${tempEmployee.phoneNumber}"></b></td>
            <td style="color:black"><b th:text="${tempEmployee.nationalNumber}"></b></td>
            <td style="color:black"><b th:text="${tempEmployee.dateOfBirth}"></b></td>
            <td style="color:black"><b th:text="${tempEmployee.dateOfEmployment}"></b></td>
            <td style="color:black"><b th:text="${tempEmployee.jopTitle}"></b></td>
            <!--Update  Link-->
            <td>
                <a th:href="@{/Employees/Show}"

                   class="btn btn-info btn-sm">
                    Add
                </a>
               

                <a th:href="@{/Employees/ShowUpdate(employeeId=${tempEmployee.id})}"
                   class="btn btn-info btn-sm">
                    Update
                </a>

                <a th:href="@{/Employees/delete(employeeId=${tempEmployee.id})}"
                   class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"
                   onclick="if(!(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this Book?'))) return false">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>

</body>
</html>
At the top of the code is the logout button
```